# Why does this program throw an exception while using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create threads that add one to a variable named sum each time. Why am I getting an exception. Also if possible, could someone let me know why the threads are occurring in order? Sorry, very very new to threads.

This is the code for the task class:

```
public class AddOneToSum extends Thread
{
    private int sum = 0;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println( this.getName() + " : Sum is " + sum );
            ++sum;
        }
    
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the main method class:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Assignment9
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Thread> arrayOfThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    
        try
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
            {
                arrayOfThreads.add( new AddOneToSum() );
                i++;
            }
    
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
            {
                arrayOfThreads.get(i).start();
            }
        }
    
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to include the exception.

Comment: Was your problem solved? Could you give some feedback

Answer (score 2):

Error occurs, because you increment `i` variable twice, then creating threads list

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
{
    arrayOfThreads.add( new AddOneToSum() );
    i++; // <--- redudant
}
```

remove `i++` in loop

But all calls to the run method will output `0`. If you really want to add the value, then change the variable to static and synchronize access to it

```
public class AddOneToSum extends Thread
{
    private static int sum = 0;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            synchronized(AddOneToSum.class) {
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " : Sum is " + sum);
                ++sum;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-1 : Sum is 0
Thread-49 : Sum is 1
Thread-46 : Sum is 2
Thread-48 : Sum is 3
Thread-42 : Sum is 4
Thread-41 : Sum is 5
Thread-38 : Sum is 6
Thread-37 : Sum is 7
Thread-30 : Sum is 8
Thread-29 : Sum is 9
Thread-34 : Sum is 10
Thread-33 : Sum is 11
Thread-26 : Sum is 12
Thread-25 : Sum is 13
Thread-45 : Sum is 14
Thread-47 : Sum is 15
Thread-44 : Sum is 16
Thread-43 : Sum is 17
Thread-40 : Sum is 18
Thread-22 : Sum is 19
Thread-39 : Sum is 20
Thread-36 : Sum is 21
Thread-35 : Sum is 22
Thread-32 : Sum is 23
Thread-31 : Sum is 24
Thread-27 : Sum is 25
Thread-24 : Sum is 26
Thread-23 : Sum is 27
Thread-28 : Sum is 28
Thread-21 : Sum is 29
Thread-20 : Sum is 30
Thread-19 : Sum is 31
Thread-18 : Sum is 32
Thread-16 : Sum is 33
Thread-17 : Sum is 34
Thread-15 : Sum is 35
Thread-14 : Sum is 36
Thread-3 : Sum is 37
Thread-12 : Sum is 38
Thread-11 : Sum is 39
Thread-10 : Sum is 40
Thread-9 : Sum is 41
Thread-8 : Sum is 42
Thread-7 : Sum is 43
Thread-6 : Sum is 44
Thread-4 : Sum is 45
Thread-13 : Sum is 46
Thread-0 : Sum is 47
Thread-5 : Sum is 48
Thread-2 : Sum is 49
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop you wrote will add 1 to i every loop, but you wrote another `i++` will make ArrayList only 25 elements, so just remove it.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
{
    arrayOfThreads.add( new AddOneToSum() );
}
```